# How I can pass to creation XmlModelList a query dynamically?

Tags: xml, qt, properties, qml, createobject

I want to dynamically create a qml object that contains an XMLListmodel.

I would like to pass a query created by myself as a property, but I don't know how to pass this property dynamically, since with create.object I can't. Is there another way?

```
element.qml

import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.12

Item {
    
    XmlListModel
    {
       id:secondaLista
        property string adding:"[2]"
        source: "file.xml"
        query: "/tag1/tag2" + adding
        XmlRole
        {
            name:"tag3"; query:"tag3/string()"
        }
        XmlRole
        {
            name:"tag4"; query:"tag4/string()"
        }

    }*/

    GridView
    {
...
```

```
function create()
{
   var component;
   var object;
   component = Qt.createComponent("element.qml");
   object= component.createObject(parent, {adding."[2]"});
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your code should be a bit different:

Element.qml

```
Item {
    id: item
    property string adding: "[2]"
    
    XmlListModel
    {
        id:secondaLista                       
        query: "/tag1/tag2" + item.adding
        ...
    }
}
```

and then:

```
function create()
{
    var component = Qt.createComponent("Element.qml");             
    var object = component.createObject(parent, { adding: "[2]" });    
}
```

**Pay attention**: As I know the custom element name must be with capitalized first character.

Comment: I tried what you wrote, but it doesn't work.
Element.qml is part of a stackview (id: stackprove) so after creating the object I use stackprove.push (object).
I tried adding in Element.qml Component.onCompleted {query = "..."} and it works.
But I wish I could the query value, can I somehow through the create () function before using stackprove.push (object)?

Comment: If you want to get some help you have to provide [mcve] instead of explaining your code and what problem you have with it.

Comment: I wrong , I passed the component instead of the object at stackview so I know because i didn't see query property result. Thanks for all